# Cannot bind a directory using --singularity-args '-B' in snakemake

Tags: python, docker, bioinformatics, snakemake, singularity-container

I have troubles running snakemake in a singularity container.
My raw data resides outside the working directory, and I am not able to access the raw data from inside the container.

Path to the raw data folder: `/data/projects/pipe_test/Fastqs/`

My simplified Snakefile looks like

```
singularity: "/home/AD/username/scripts/test.sif"
rule fastqc:
  shell: """
          ls Fastqs > fastqs.txt 2>&1"""
```

Executing snakemake from the folder wih the snakefile with

```
snakemake  -c1 --use-singularity --singularity-args '--bind /data/projects/pipe_test/Fastqs/:$PWD/Fastqs/'
```

throws an error because the Fastq directory does not exist inside the container:

```
Error in rule fastqc:
    jobid: 0
    shell:

          ls Fastqs > fastqs.txt 2>&1
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

*What I tried:*

- I tried --singularity-args omitting the rigth part starting with the colon. The directory is then mounted but not in Fastqs but in the src location.
- `--bind /data/projects/pipe_test/Fastqs/:/Fastqs/` also mounts the directory, but in the root directory.
- Running singularity shell correctly mounts the directory at the correct path and the raw data is accessibe:

```
singularity shell --bind /data/projects/pipe_test/Fastqs/:$PWD/Fastqs test.sif
```

However, I expect the raw data in ./Fastqs of the container when running the snakemake command.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much!